# Android: How to sort paths by last folders name?

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, collections, compare

**Question**

How can I sort paths by their last folder name?

**What I know**

I know that I can sort my ArrayList this way:

```
    Collections.sort(aL_dirsWithPicsInside, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    });
```

Output:

```
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/Army
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/DCIM/Camera
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/DCIM/Canyoning
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/DCIM/Eigene Fotos/28.11.2015 - Arosa Eichhörnchenweg
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/Guns
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Friends
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Südafrika
```

So it sorts the whole string.

What I need is this output (sort by last folder name):

```
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/DCIM/Eigene Fotos/28.11.2015 - Arosa Eichhörnchenweg
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/Army
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/DCIM/Camera
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/DCIM/Canyoning
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Friends
/storage/5AA6-2B7E/Guns
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Südafrika
```

Comment: Do you want to sort by last modified folders?

Comment: No only by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(aL_dirsWithPicsInside, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] segments1 = s1.split("/");
        String[] segments2 = s2.split("/");
        return segments1[segments1.length-1].compareToIgnoreCase(segments2[segments2.length-1]);
    }
});
```

In addition, you should control that path is correct and it has last part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Collections.sort(aL_dirsWithPicsInside, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            String str1 = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf("/")+1,s1.length());
            String str2 = s2.substring(s2.lastIndexOf("/")+1,s2.length());
            return str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2);
        }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Klevin. But it sorts the paths the same way. 
The solution vom Miller did the trick and I marked it as accepted answer.

Comment: No problem, i actually up-voted his answer because it is more general and it compares every sub directory of the paths